# My random replace-system replaces the wrong items

Tags: python, string, random, replace

I want to build a program that replaces 12345 with one of each item from the shuflo list, but if the shuflo list contains a number from 1 to 5 it will replace them too.

Here is my code:

```
shuflo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def build(x):
    random.shuffle(shuflo)
    lock = shuflo
    lack = str(x)
    lack = lack.replace("1", str(lock[0]))
    lack = lack.replace("2", str(lock[1]))
    lack = lack.replace("3", str(lock[2]))
    lack = lack.replace("4", str(lock[3]))
    lack = lack.replace("5", str(lock[4]))
    Ponf = [lack, eval(lack)]
    return Ponf

print(build("(1)+(2)+(3)+(4)+(5)"))
```

The typical outcome would be:

```
['(3)+(1)+(2)+(3)+(5)', 14]
```

In the list shuflo there is only one of 3, but some of the elements get replaced twice so it doesn't work.

How can i fix this???

Comment: Say 1 is replaced with 3. When you replace 3, you'll replace both original 3s and the 1s that have already been changed. You need to do all changes in one pass.

Comment: @Reti43 how would i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform the replacement of each number only once.  This can be done with the `re` module or, if the numbers are only one character long (i.e. from 0 to 9 only), it can be done in a list comprehension going through each character of the string.

Using regular a expression:

```
import random
import re

def build(x,shuflo=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]):
    shuffled = random.sample(shuflo,len(shuflo))
    d = {str(i):str(v) for i,v in zip(shuflo,shuffled)}
    pattern = "|".join(sorted(d,key=len,reverse=True))
    return re.sub(pattern,lambda c:d[c.group()],x)

build("(1)+(2)+(3)+(4)+(5)")
'(5)+(3)+(2)+(4)+(1)'
```

Using a list comprehension (single character replacements):

```
import random

def build(x,shuflo=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]):
    shuffled = random.sample(shuflo,len(shuflo))
    d = {str(i):str(v) for i,v in zip(shuflo,shuffled)}
    return "".join(d.get(c,c) for c in x)

build("(1)+(2)+(3)+(4)+(5)")
'(1)+(4)+(5)+(2)+(3)'
```

maketrans also works for single character replacements:

```
def build(x,shuflo=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]):
    shuffled = random.sample(shuflo,len(shuflo))
    d = {str(i):str(v) for i,v in zip(shuflo,shuffled)}
    return x.translate(str.maketrans(d))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```py
import random

shuflo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def build(x):
    random.shuffle(shuflo)
    lack = str(x)
    table = str.maketrans({str(i): str(shuflo[i-1]) for i in range(1,len(shuflo)+1})
    lack = lack.translate(table)
    Ponf = [lack, eval(lack)]
    return Ponf

print(build("(1)+(2)+(3)+(4)+(5)"))
```

This could definitely be optimized a lot, but I am not sure of your exact use case.

Comment: Wow! thats a lot of code, but do i need to import something for this to work? Because in my case i get alot of errors.

Comment: I'm currently working on an improved version, give me 5 minutes.

Comment: @Miklath, can you check if it works, you should not need to import anything but `random`? If it gives you errors could you let us know what they say?

Comment: Sure, Can i send you a screenshot? if so how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/, just add the image to your original post and add something like: "I am getting the following error when I run X"

Comment: Your new version works great! No errors anymore. Thanks alot!

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget to accept the answer if it was useful.

Comment: Also... would this work with other numbers then just 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5?

Comment: You could theoretically build any dictionary that you want to use to replace the values of `lack`. Just make sure to insert the dictionary into the `str.maketrans()` statement. The code as it is will generate a dict from `shuflo` starting at 1 and going up to n.